# GDI+ GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP in C++

Tags: c++, gdi+

here is my function im trying to create bitmap from hbitmap here. But im getting identifier not found error.

```
    __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall testFunction()
{
    int W = 860, H = 720;

    int iLeft = 0, iRight = 860;
    int iTop = 0, iBottom = 720;

    int iW = iRight - iLeft, iH = iBottom - iTop;

    HWND bluestacks =  FindWindow(L"BlueStacksApp", L"BlueStacks App Player");
    HDC bHDC = GetWindowDC(bluestacks);
    HDC cHDC = CreateCompatibleDC(bHDC);
    HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap( bHDC, W, H);

    HGDIOBJ sO =  SelectObject( cHDC, bmp);
    BOOL pW =PrintWindow( bluestacks, cHDC, 0);
    SelectObject(cHDC, bmp);
    BitBlt(cHDC, 0, 0, iW, iH, bHDC, iLeft, iTop, 0x00CC0020);
    Bitmap newBitmap = GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(bmp);

}
```

Error code:

identifier "GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP" is undefined

Note loaded header files:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <Gdiplusflat.h> // Gdiplusflat.h
#include <ostream>
```

Comment: `GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP` takes three arguments and you only seem to be providing one.

Comment: @JonathanPotter When I'm trying possible solutions I changed arguments but It just doesnt matter when error is identifier is undefined

Comment: Curious: Does auto newBitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(bmp, nullptr); build? Should use same underlying API

Answer (score 0):

The function is defined as follows:

```
GpStatus WINGDIPAPI GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(HBITMAP hbm,
                        HPALETTE hpal,
                        GpBitmap** bitmap);
```

if you want to get a Bitmap object from a HBITMAP, maybe you shoud use the constructor

```
Bitmap(HBITMAP,HPALETTE);
```

for your code it should be:

```
Bitmap newBitmap(bmp,NULL);
```

BTW:before use this, you should initialize GDIPLUS.

Answer (score 0):

works for me, after adding additional option to linker `-lgdiplus -mwindows`

```
g++ test.c -lgdiplus -mwindows
```